# Сервис не стартует, не видит модуль

Tags: perl, centos

Всем привет! 
Centos 7
Сервис ругается на блок (файл dklab_realplexor.pl) с просьбой установки EV:

```
    use strict;
BEGIN {
    if (!eval('use EV; 1')) {
        print STDERR "Error: EV library is not found in your system:\n";
        print STDERR "http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/EV-3.9/EV.pm\n";
        print STDERR "You must install EV, e.g.:\n";
        print STDERR "# yum install gcc\n";
        print STDERR "# perl -MCPAN -e \"install EV\"\n";
        print STDERR "  - or -\n";
        print STDERR "# apt-get install gcc\n";
        print STDERR "# perl -MCPAN -e \"install EV\"\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Хотя он есть и отрабатывает другие команды. Вот сама ошибка:

```
-- Начат процесс запуска юнита dklab_realplexor.service.                                                                                     
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]: Error: EV library is not found in your system:                      
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]: http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/EV-3.9/EV.pm                       
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]: You must install EV, e.g.:                                          
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]: # yum install gcc                                                   
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]: # perl -MCPAN -e "install EV"                                       
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]:   - or -                                                            
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]: # apt-get install gcc                                               
окт 08 20:44:09 realplexor/dklab_realplexor.conf[11491]: # perl -MCPAN -e "install EV"                                       
окт 08 20:44:10 dklab_realplexor[11482]: FAILED: /etc/dklab_realplexor.conf; see logs                                        
окт 08 20:44:10 systemd[1]: PID file /var/run/dklab_realplexor_*.pid not readable (yet?) after start.                        
окт 08 20:44:10 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Dklab Realplexor Comet Server..
-- Subject: Ошибка юнита dklab_realplexor.service                                                                                            
-- Defined-By: systemd                                                                                                                       
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel                                                                      
--                                                                                                                                           
-- Произошел сбой юнита dklab_realplexor.service.                                                                                            
--                                                                                                                                           
-- Результат: failed.                                                                                                                        
окт 08 20:44:10 systemd[1]: Unit dklab_realplexor.service entered failed state.                                              
окт 08 20:44:10 systemd[1]: dklab_realplexor.service failed.
```

При этом не работает из этого места (файл dklab_realplexor.int):

```
    CWD="/opt/dklab_realplexor"
    ADDCONFIG="/etc/dklab_realplexor.conf"
    LOGTAG='realplexor/`basename $CONF`'
    LOGPRI='local3.info'
    PIDPREFIX="/var/run/dklab_realplexor"

    NAME=`basename $0`
    if [ ${NAME:0:1} = "S" -o ${NAME:0:1} = "K" ]; then
        NAME=${NAME:3}
    fi
    [ -f /etc/default/${NAME} ] && . /etc/default/${NAME}
    [ -f /etc/sysconfig/${NAME} ] && . /etc/sysconfig/${NAME}

    if [ -x $CWD/dklab_realplexor ]; then
        BIN="$CWD/dklab_realplexor"
    else
        BIN="perl $CWD/dklab_realplexor.pl"
    fi
start () {
    export CONF
    for CONF in $ADDCONFIG; do
        PIDFILE=${PIDPREFIX}_`basename $CONF`.pid
        PID=`cat $PIDFILE 2>/dev/null`
        if [ "$PID" != "" ] && kill -s 0 $PID 2>/dev/null; then
            echo "dklab_realplexor for $CONF is already running"
        else
            rm -f $PIDFILE 2>/dev/null
            cd $CWD && $BIN $CONF -p $PIDFILE 2>&1 | logger -p `eval "echo $LOGPRI"` -t `eval "echo $LOGTAG"` &
            sleep 1
            PID=`cat $PIDFILE 2>/dev/null`
            if [ "$PID" != "" ]; then
                echo "OK: $CONF"
            else
                echo "FAILED: $CONF; see logs"
            fi
        fi
    done
}
```

Если запускать сам dklab_realplexor.pl файл вот так:

```
perl ./dklab_realplexor.pl /etc/dklab_realplexor.conf
```

всё хорошо отрабатывает, ошибок нет.
Может есть идеи почему? Помогите, пожалуйста.

Сам файл сервиса:

```
[Unit]
Description=realplexor
#After=syslog.target
#After=network.target
#After=nginx.service
#After=mysql.service
#Requires=mysql.service
#Wants=redis.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/dklab_realplexor_dklab_realplexor.conf.pid
WorkingDirectory=/opt/dklab_realplexor

User=root
Group=root

Environment=RACK_ENV=production

OOMScoreAdjust=-1000

ExecStart=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int start
ExecStop=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int stop
ExecReload=/opt/dklab_realplexor/dklab_realplexor.int reload
TimeoutSec=5000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Выполняю скрипт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Data::Dump qw/ pp /;

print pp \%ENV;
```

Из сервиса:

```
Nov 15 13:01:34 game 123.int: Can't locate Data/Dump.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /opt/dklab_realplexor/123.int line 2.
Nov 15 13:01:34 game 123.int: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/dklab_realplexor/123.int line 2.
```

Вручную:

```
[root@game ~]# perl /opt/dklab_realplexor/123.int
Can't locate Data/Dump.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3 /root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /root/perl5/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /opt/dklab_realplexor/123.int line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/dklab_realplexor/123.int line 2.
```

Comment: Такое впечатление, что при старте из сервиса он вообще не определяет perl и ничего о модулях не знает.

Answer (score 2):

Сервисы обычно имеют свои переменные окружения. Поэтому если скрипт запускает операционная система, то у вас не хватает настроек.

Запустите этот скрипт от себя и как сервис и посмотрите разницу:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

print $^V, "\n"; # Напечатает версию

use Data::Dump qw/ pp /;

print pp \%ENV;
```

Скорей всего нужно будет подправить `PATH` и `PERL5LIB`

**UPD**

Без зависимостей:

```
while( my( $key, $value ) =  each %ENV ) {
    print "$key - $value\n";
}
```

**UPD**

Судя из конфига, что у вас в примере. Для настройки переменных окружения нужно использовать:

```
Environment=PERL5LIB=<path>:<path>:<path>
```

Comment: добавил результат в конец описания запроса.

Comment: @Relajado, ну так поставьте Data::Dump :) Хотя и так очевидно, что пути совсем разные.

Comment: @PinkTux, я не совсем понимаю где править чтобы из сервисов работало.

Comment: @Relajado, в ответе есть: переменная среды `PERL5LIB`. Где её выставлять - в ответе на другой вопрос, про perl под рутом.

Comment: @PinkTux: нее, даже если поставить оно работать не будет. Изначальна проблема же в этом.

Comment: @EugenKonkov, а это как ставить - через `yum` или `cpan` :) Может в каком-то случае и упадёт куда есть доступ у сервиса. В `/usr/local/share/perl5` какой-нибудь, например.

Comment: @PinkTux `cpan Module::Name` Не понятно какую версию перла тот сервис ещё видит.

Comment: @PinkTux, @EugenKonkov я пробовал сменить `PERL5LIB` в `/root/.bashrc`, но это не помогло. `PATH` отличается только добавлением в конце `/root/bin`, но если обновляю в `/root/.bashrc` то всё равно ничего не меняется, из под сервиса он видит старые значения.

Comment: @Relajado, как вариант можно добавить в начало скрипта: `use lib qw(путь1 путь2 путь3);`

Comment: @PinkTux, да, это помогло и сервис запустился. Но как исправить глобальнее?) Не писать же в каждом скрипте одно и то же если он запускается из под сервиса)

Comment: @Relajado: Что у вас в окружении вы так и не показали

Comment: @EugenKonkov, `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`